# Singleton database object with parameterized initialization on startup?

Tags: database, singleton, lazy-loading, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I'm attempting to create a single database instance that can be used by multiple classes (using `object` keyword in Kotlin). However, I wanted to be able to specify the database name before the singleton instance is created.

Since a singleton object cannot be initialized with a parameter, I was wondering if what I'm doing is valid, or if there's a better way of doing things:

```
object DatabaseSingleton {

    private lateinit var databaseName: String
    private lateinit var mongoClient: MongoClient

    val database: DatabaseContainer by lazy {
        DatabaseContainer(databaseName, mongoClient)
    }

    fun init(databaseName: String, mongoClient: MongoClient): DatabaseSingleton {
        this.databaseName = databaseName
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient
        return this
    }
}
```

And in another file

```
class DatabaseContainer(databaseName: String, val mongoClient: MongoClient) {

    val db: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName)
    val table: MongoCollection<Settings> = db.getCollection<Settings>(TABLE_NAME)

}
```

Basically, I'm encapsulating a "database container" in the singleton object by using lazy initialization for the database container and providing lateinit vars for specifying the database name and having an initialization function in the singleton object to initialize the database container. This is so that in my main method when I first start up my application, I can load the database name from some local properties file and call `val database = DatabaseSingleton.init("DATABASE_NAME", client)` to create my database singleton that needs to be accessed by multiple other classes.

Is this a good approach to do what I want, or are there better ways of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

try to get the databaseName from a system property(or system environment variable). You can set the property in your starting script.

for example: `java -DdatabaseName=databaseA ....`

```
object DatabaseSingleton {
    private const var DB_NAME_SYS_KEY = "databaseName"

    private lateinit var databaseName: String
    private lateinit var mongoClient: MongoClient

    val database: DatabaseContainer by lazy {
        DatabaseContainer(databaseName, mongoClient)
    }

    fun init(mongoClient: MongoClient): DatabaseSingleton {
        this.databaseName = System.getProperty(DB_NAME_SYS_KEY)
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient
        return this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will change it to a system property in that case.
Still, is the approach with lazy loading and lateinits a valid approach?